# check for unsaved form before moving to another form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using Asp.net Javascript and C#

I have a content page, and left  side has links in the master page.The content page has data entry form. If user leaves the page without submitting the form and click the cancel button. user should be prompt to save the changes made. I know i can use window.onbeforeleave and can show the confirm message.

Below is the issue.

1. The control moves to executing the code behind page of the clicked link.Reason is on clicking the link, a javascript function is being called. this function has below code.

   window.location.href = 'anotherpage.aspx'
2. The confirm message appears later.

My query is, Is there any way to show the confirm message first.

I cannot write the confirmation message code in java script function as there are so many other links in left menu and same situation can arrise to prompt the user for confirmation message and logic is different in all pages to check the unsaved forms.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use jQuery for a '**dirty check**' . And there are 2 ways to implement it.

1. Based on jQuery data feature : http://www.mydogboris.com/2009/10/using-jquery-data-feature-to-detect-form-changes/
2. a jQuery plugin for dirty check : http://www.novogeek.com/post/2010/01/31/Check-for-unsaved-data-on-your-web-forms-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: 1. my page is content page so how to pass the formid. 2. My form is not disabling the buttons.

Comment: can you detect when the focus is changing ? from content page to master page

Comment: can you suggest something got the same ?

Comment: Same implementation is required for headers. I have 14 links in header and same number of links in left menu.